# Vaadin URL mapping issues: sub-path URL mapping and automatic URL mapping not working

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

Facing these issue w.r.t Vaadin UI and URL mapping.

**Problem1:**

I am trying to use Vaadin for basic CRUD operations for my Entities. To start with, I would like to expose a UI class to /subpath/xyz url. But the sub-path url mapping is somehow not working. (Please note that when I keep or remove @Spring(path="myui") it still maps to localhost:8080/myui/  and not  localhost:8080/subpath/myui/

What am I missing?

I have been following Vaadin's documentation but no luck so far.
https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-environment.html#application.environment.servlet-mapping

**Problem2:**
Also, Vaadin is not generating url mappings automatically from the class name. E.g. MyUI classname should be mapped to localhost:8080/my-ui/ if I do not give path attribute in @SpringUI( as per Vaadin's documents).

```
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Title;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;


import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@Theme("valo")
@Title("My UI")
@SpringUI(path="myui")
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        // Create the content root layout for the UI
        VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
        setContent(content);

        // Display the greeting
        content.addComponent(new Label("Hello World!"));

        // Have a clickable button
        content.addComponent(new Button("Click Me!",
            click -> Notification.show("Clicked!")));
    }
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/admin/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    package vaadinUI;

    import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
    import com.vaadin.annotations.Title;
    import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
    import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
    import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
    import com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServlet;
    import com.vaadin.ui.*;


    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

    @Theme("valo")
    @Title("My UI")
    @SpringUI(path="myui/subpath")
    public class MyUISubPath extends UI {
        @Override
        protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
            // Create the content root layout for the UI
            VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
            setContent(content);

            // Display the greeting
            content.addComponent(new Label("Hello World!"));

            // Have a clickable button
            content.addComponent(new Button("Click Me!",
                click -> Notification.show("Clicked!")));
        }
    }


package vaadinUI;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Title;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;


import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@Theme("valo")
@Title("My UI")
@SpringUI(path="myui")
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        // Create the content root layout for the UI
        VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
        setContent(content);

        // Display the greeting
        content.addComponent(new Label("Hello World!"));

        // Have a clickable button
        content.addComponent(new Button("Click Me!",
            click -> Notification.show("Clicked!")));
    }
}
```

I am using 8.0.X and this works for me. You may have to change some things. Reusing the same UI class in different paths may not be that advisable. Or the framework rejects this by design

Problem 2: "An empty string (default) will map the UI to the root of the servlet" the way I read it is to map to ....:8080/

**EDIT**

Misread version of docs

**EDIT**

I tried your code and it behaves as I described too. @SpringUI() maps to root and with path maps to path. The UI mapped to myui/subpath works as expected. So I would start with a new project, and refresh the .m2 repo.

FYI the values in @WebServlet take priority over the ones @VaadinServletConfiguration

Are you refreshing/reloading on the browser side? You could restart the container (totally brute force) and reload the page to see if its makes a difference

Comment: Actually the docs are now by default for v8, while v7 has a different path `https://vaadin.com/docs7/-/part7.....`

Comment: I am using the same version with spring 1.5.3 release and the code I posted works as described in the answer. @SpringUI() maps to root of servlet and @SpringUI(path="myui") maps to /myui. @SpringUI(path="myui/subpath") maps to /myui/subpath.